# Trying to sync a dataset in Amazon Cognito returns CognitoSyncError

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

```
let dataset: AWSCognitoDataset = self.syncClient.openOrCreateDataset(name)    
dataset.synchronize()
```

> AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCognitoDataset.m line:503 | __30-[AWSCognitoDataset syncPush:]_block_invoke | An error occured attempting to update records: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoSyncErrorDomain Code=8 "Lambda function returned an invalid output. Please check your JSON structure." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Lambda function returned an invalid output. Please check your JSON structure., NSLocalizedFailureReason=InvalidLambdaFunctionOutputException:}

The error occurs for a specific dataset every time. The dataset JSON is valid. Any idea why is this happening? How can I get more info on the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error here indicates that your Sync trigger Lambda function is not returning the service contract output in expected format.

Sync triggers follow the service provider interface programming paradigm.  Cognito will provide input in a specific JSON format to your Lambda function and it expects the return value to be the same format.

The [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-events.html) has the format documented with an example lambda function.